# how to get letter of integer number in xcode

Tags: objective-c, integer

I want one function that give to me word of numbers from integer value.
For example when I to give one integer value like `3` this function should return to me `three`.

In other words this function gets integer value and return string (word of number) value.

Also I want this language to be persian(farsi). For example when I send `3` value to function that return `سه` value

Comment: lol... and you don't know how to do that?